# Check if given port number already in used using wix installer

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer, wix3.8

I am developing an wix installer for deploying a website . I achieved this by referring [this blog](http://blog.bartdemeyer.be/2013/10/create-an-installer-for-website-with-wix-part-1/)  and its working perfectly for me .But now i need to get the port number from user and need to publish under that port. For that i have create a custom UI Dialog in wix and getting port number from user and deploying website in that port .But now i need to check whether the port number which is given by the user is already in use ! if its already in use then i need to notify the user and wants him to change the port number.

How to do this ..? Is it possible..?

Comment: yes , everything is possible through wix custom action

Comment: @FromStuckToFlow how toi do this ..?

Comment: You create new Custom action project  , create custom action function and check if port 443 is in use (for secure SSL) , u can set the result to wix property and do something

Comment: @FromStuckToFlow Thanks for the reply .I will try ;0